# the best haproxy architecture?

Tags: load-balancing, virtual-machines, haproxy, high-availability, keepalived

I have two servers running ldap with replication between them, now i need to install a loadbalancer, so what i have in mind is:

```
vm1: ldap1
vm2: ldap1(replication)
vm3: haproxy1 + keepalived
vm4: haproxy2 + keepalived
```

vm4 will be backup for vm3, and vm3 will be in charge of loadbalance for trafic towards vm1 and vm2.

My question is: can i install haproxy and keepalived on the same vms running ldap? soemthing like this:

```
 vm1: ldap + haproxy(master) + keepalived
 vm2: ldap(replication) + haproxy(slave) + keepalived
```

if the answer is yes, what are the pros and cons of each architecture?

Comment: you need to install haproxy and keepalived only on vm3 and vm4, for cluster on linux use pacemaker

Comment: yeah, but why not on the same vm that host ldap?

Comment: because, haproxy distribute the load to the backends servers, looking in google haproxy and using tab images, you can understand the reason.